# How to configure azure pipeline to retry only failed tests

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that runs a bunch of tests. I'm using retryCountOnTaskFailure but the issue I have is sometimes 1 flaky test fails, the task re-runs but it runs all the tests again including all the tests that passed. Not ideal.

Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Fix the flaky test. Working around it in pipeline is not the way to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Based on your latest update/requirement to use ubuntu agents machine to rerun `dotnet test` for failed tests only, you may refer and test to run this [PowerShell script](https://github.com/hlaueriksson/ConductOfCode/blob/master/TestRerun/test.ps1).

To make the parameter `` $parameters = "-- TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=\`"Retry\`", value=\`"$i\`")" `` works on ubuntu machine, we can edit it as `` $parameters = "-- TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=`"Retry`", value=`"$i`")" ``

Here is a workaround to get and modify the script for ubuntu agent environment -> run `dotnet test` and rerun failed tests. (The same .net project I tested with `VSTest`, which had 2 tests - one was passed and the other was failed; we could see only the failed tests were rerun.)

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- powershell: |
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hlaueriksson/ConductOfCode/master/TestRerun/test.ps1" -OutFile "test.ps1"
      sed -i 's/\\\\/`/g; s/\\`/`/g' test.ps1
      .\test.ps1 -retries 3
  displayName: Use PS script to rerun dotnet test for failed tests
```

[image]

See more details in [Retry flaky tests with dotnet test and PowerShell](https://conductofcode.io/post/retry-flaky-tests-with-dotnet-test-and-powershell/)

In addition, per the built-in `DotNetCoreCLI` pipeline task, it doesn't support the `Rerun failed tests` feature as that of `VSTest` task in Windows agent environment. For this, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

---

The functionality of `retryCountOnTaskFailure` will only make the pipeline rerun the whole failed step. If testing with the `VSTest` pipeline task, you may use the `Rerun failed tests` feature of this task instead of rerunning the test step.

From the sample below we could see there were 2 tests during my `VSTest` step; one test was passed and the other was failed; in the next attempts, only the failed test was executed.

```
- task: VSTest@3
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    rerunFailedTests: true
    rerunFailedThreshold: '90'
  displayName: VS Test
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am restricted to Ubuntu agents and this task is only for Windows :-(